# Identifying the type of random variable in experiment

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A manufacturing company uses an acceptance scheme on items from a production line before they are shipped. The plan is a two-stage one. Boxes of 20 items are readied for shipment, and a sample of 10 items is tested for defectives. If any defectives are found, the entire box is sent back for 100% screening. If no defectives are found, the box is shipped.

In this case, which random variable is applicable? I thought that binomial random variable doesn't apply since the experiment doesn't follow a repetition of trials. Would it be a Bernoulli random variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the probability of being faulty is independent for each item, it looks to me like a binomial distribution, as you suggested. If $p$ is the probability of an item of being faulty, the probability of NOT detecting any faulty item in ten samples taken from the box will be:

$$
Pr(k=10) = {10\choose10}(1-p)^{10}p^0 = (1-p)^{10}
$$

Hence, the probability of a box to be sent to screening is:
$$
Pr(k \ge 1) = 1 - (1-p)^{10}
$$

If the probability is not independent across items (for instance, if a machine has an error it may affect several item in a row that may be packed in the same box), then you may need to consider conditional probabilities and perhaps use likelihood or Bayesian inference to estimate the additional parameters.